# Mongo query on custom date system

Tags: python, mongodb

I need to be able to query documents that have a date field between some range, but sometimes in my dataset the year doesn't matter (this is represented with a boolean flag in the mongo document).

So, for example, I might have a document for Christmas (12/25-- year doesn't matter) and another document for 2014 World Cup Final Match (8/13/2014). If the user searches for dates between 8/1/2014 and 12/31/2014, both of those documents should match, but another document for 2010 World Cup Final Match would not.

All approaches I've gotten to work so far have used a complicated nesting of $and and $or statements, which ends up being too slow for production, even with indexes set appropriately. Is there a simple or ideal way to handle this kind of conditional date searching in mongo?

Comment: Could you edit your question to include some sample documents and queries that better illustrate what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

For me you have to store specific values you'll search on, and index them.

For example, alongside with the date, you may store "year", "month", and "day", index on "month" and "day", and do your queries on it.

You may want to store them as "y", "m", and "d" to gain some bytes (That's sad, I know).